# Bootstrap list group show only three item at time

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap list group and want to show only three item at a time.

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">First item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Fourth item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Fifth item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Six item</a>
</div>
```

Size of each list item can vary.

Please help , if any slider/collapse action can implement.

Comment: What you want to do after showing three items? Do you want the next ones on another page or whats the purpose of the question?

Comment: Use http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse and make the first 3 open using 'in'

Comment: I want to show some sort of small icon on clicking on that it should expand remaining items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a custom solution I came up with. We essentially use the index of the elements to hide anything after the 3rd, and a Boolean to toggle the effect.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/yz78f0gd/)

```
var hideElements = function(){
    $('#collapse-list a').each(function(i){
        if(i > 2){
            $(this).slideToggle(200);
        }
    });
};

hideElements();
var toggleStatus = true;
$('#toggle-collapse').click(function(){
    if(toggleStatus){
        $('#collapse-list .list-group-item:not(:visible)').slideToggle(200);
    } else {
        hideElements();
    }
    toggleStatus = !toggleStatus;
});
```

Comment: This hides all other element, I want some thing which will hide and show other items.

Comment: Thanks @wrxsti that's what i exactly want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use boostrap carousel for this:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner list-group" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">1 item</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">2 item</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">3 item</a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">4 item</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">5 item</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">6 item</a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">7 item</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">8 item</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">9 item</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3hysdaz6/)

Comment: Thnaks @makshh this would help.